# Why session_start() would try to open a file?

Tags: php, session, opencart

I've got an warning message with my site saying "session_start(): open(/home/content/55/5307955/tmp/sess_qphb8rav2kmt5kavptqh1mik06, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) ". I've been reading basics about PHP session and `seesion_start()`, so far I understand that when `session_start` it either starts a new session or resume the existing session. What does it have to do with opening a file?

Comment: Because session information stored where? In a file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory permissions on that directory structure. It can't open (or create) the tmp files need to store session data.